# How can I retrieve Git LFS files for Unreal Engine 5

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, unreal-engine5

I am a newbie to `UE5` and `Git`.
Yesterday I've worked on some functionalities for my `UE5` project and when I was done, I saved the project and committed the changes to my GitHub repo.

Today, when I tried to continue working on my project I saw that some things, but not all of the changes, were missing from the `UE5` content browser. I took a look into the project directory and yes, these files are indeed there, but when I open them in VS I see that they are `LFS` pointer files and `UE5` can't see them.

How can I retrieve them for `UE5` without having to start over again?

I've read some answers to problem kinda similar to mine and tried using `git lfs checkout` `git lfs fetch` or `git lfs push --all` but as a total newbie I'm not sure what they are doing and yes, they didn't fix my issue.

Edit: output of running `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git lfs pull` (I've skipped listing every asset here, because it would be too long. Indeed LFS listed every asset, even those missing ones)

```
19:10:03.389848 exec-cmd.c:244          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
19:10:03.396759 git.c:749               trace: exec: git-lfs pull
19:10:03.396759 run-command.c:659       trace: run_command: git-lfs pull
19:10:03.413239 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'version'
19:10:03.467970 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' '--git-dir' '--show-toplevel'
19:10:03.515017 trace git-lfs: exec: uname
19:10:03.558384 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
19:10:03.588318 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '--includes' '--local' 'lfs.repositoryformatversion'
19:10:03.619662 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '--includes' '-l'
19:10:03.648823 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
19:10:03.680204 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '--includes' '-l' '--blob' ':.lfsconfig'
19:10:03.710582 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '--includes' '-l' '--blob' 'HEAD:.lfsconfig'
19:10:03.742107 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' 'HEAD' '--symbolic-full-name' 'HEAD'
19:10:03.776202 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' 'HEAD' '--symbolic-full-name' 'HEAD'
19:10:03.804317 trace git-lfs: tq: running as batched queue, batch size of 100
19:10:03.805431 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'ls-tree' '-r' '-l' '-z' '--full-tree' '076b86abd8bf39b957600f4b3165891afc56aeff'
19:10:03.809660 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' '--git-common-dir'
19:10:03.874097 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting ".gitattributes"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting ".gitignore"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Config/DefaultEditor.ini"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Config/DefaultEditorPerProjectUserSettings.ini"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Config/DefaultGame.ini"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Content/Assets/Animations/Manny/Mobility/W2_CrouchWalk_Aim_F_Loop.uasset"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Content/Assets/Animations/Manny/Mobility/W2_CrouchWalk_Aim_F_Loop_IPC.uasset"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Content/Assets/Animations/Manny/Mobility/W2_Crouch_Aim_Idle_v2.uasset"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Content/Assets/Animations/Manny/Mobility/W2_Crouch_Aim_Idle_v2_IPC.uasset"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Content/Assets/Animations/Manny/Mobility/W2_Crouch_Aim_Point_Center.uasset"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Content/Assets/Animations/Manny/Mobility/W2_Crouch_Aim_Point_D90.uasset"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Content/Assets/Animations/Manny/Mobility/W2_Crouch_Aim_Point_U90.uasset"
19:10:03.874312 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "Content/Assets/Animations/Manny/Mobility/W2_Crouch_Fire_Single.uasset"
19:10:13.725078 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: creating pattern ".git" of type gitignore
19:10:13.725078 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: creating pattern "**/.git" of type gitignore
19:10:13.725078 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "tmp"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of running `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git lfs pull` as a code block (not an image).

Comment: @bk2204 done, I've skipped listing every asset here, because it would be too long. Indeed LFS listed every asset, even those missing ones.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that you need to run `git lfs install` after installing Git LFS.  This is required once per user and per system, and it sets up your `~/.gitconfig` file to ask Git to invoke Git LFS when checking out files.  (Thus, if you overwrite your `~/.gitconfig`, you need to run it again unless you've incorporated them into your version.)  If you're not in a repository, it's fine to run this with `--skip-repo`, which will avoid setting up the local repo (which will be done on demand by Git LFS when invoked).

However, that won't fix the current state.  It should be sufficient to run `git lfs pull`, which is like running `git lfs fetch` and then `git lfs checkout`.  That will download the files if they're not on the system, and then update the working tree.  However, those commands don't work if you haven't run `git lfs install`, so that needs to be done first.

Comment: It still haven't resolved my problem. I did `git lfs install` and `git lfs pull` in the project directory and nothing has changed. `git lfs pull` didn't give me any output. `UE5` still doesn't recognize these files and I can't see them in Content Browser.